# Exporting PDF in SAP Business Objects HTML not showing

Tags: business-objects

So my client is using SAP Business Objects Web intelligence to render reports, there are sections that have HTML from our DB these are from Rich Text Controls on the website front end, 
Everything renders fine in the report when using HTML, however when we export the report to pdf it mostly does not render, we did have 1 user render the html and we thought it was because they had ADOBE acrobat Pro but we installed this on others and now still no html. we are currently using hyperlink but that looses a lot of html like font and bold

any ideas would be much appreciated